# iOS animate UITabBarController swipe; View overlaps status bar - only on first load

Tags: ios, animation, layout, swipe, tabbar

I try to animate a left/right swipe of TabBarControllers views by myself. When you swipe, the new incoming view is shifted up by the height of the iOS status bar. So, its directly attached to the top of the screen and overlapping the status bar. When the animation finished, the view jumps down to the correct position. 
This only occurs on first load of the views/when view has not been loaded yet. In case of failure isViewLoaded was false before animation starts.

```
    UIView.transition(from: selectedViewController!.view, to: getTabView(index),
    duration: 0.3, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve,
    completion: { _ in selectedIndex = index })

    ...

    func getTabView(_ index:Int) -> UIView {
      if self.viewControllers![index].isViewLoaded {
        //print "loaded" - all fine - view's position is correct
        //tried loadView() but doesnt change anything
      }
      else {
        //print "first load" - view is shifted up
      }
      return viewControllers![index].view //when accessing .view, the view is loaded anyway (docs)
    }
```

By the way, the problem doesnt occur when I switch the tabs via the tabBar-buttons.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's still strange but I fixed it.
First I set up a UITabBarControllerDelegate to CrossDissolve between tabs when touching the Tabbar Buttons. 
Because this works without the glitch, I thought I could somehow call the delegate function

```
    tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
```

programmatically instead of

```
    UIView.transition(from: selectedViewController!.view, to: getTabView(index),
    duration: 0.3, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve,
    completion: { _ in selectedIndex = index })
```

This does not work, there was another glitch. But it was somehow obvious before because I read its not intended to call this delegate function directly. 
By trying this and that it worked suddenly. Accidentally I had uncommented both: delegate function call and right after the UIView.transition. This works.